# If soul is everywhere, then what is leaving the body at the time of death?

Tags: brahman, atma

If the whole universe is soul itself, then what is leaving at the time of death? i.e. if the soul is in me, and the same soul is in air, then what is leaving the body?

If the soul is everywhere, then it must be in the dead body also, then why are we saying that the soul is leaving the body?

Comment: You are ‘the soul’. It is you that will leave the Sthula Sharira (body), which is temporary, only for this lifetime. The soul is not everywhere. The whole universe is Brahman or God, not the soul

Comment: Questions like this one my seem to raise a confusion between the two different mainstream approaches in interpreting philosophy of Vedanta, namely monism Vedanta such as Advaita, and those which are not pure monism but admit some form of duality such as Dvaita, Visista-advaita, Acintya bheda-abheda, etc. For pure monists there is only one soul in the world and it is everywhere, omnipresent, and that can rise a confusion as to how that omnipresent soul can leave the body at death. ...

Comment: ... On the other hand such confusion doesn't arise in those other systems of Vedanta which I mentioned because they admit plurality of souls and thus they teach that there is one omnipresent soul called paramatma. He doesn't travel and doesn't leave the body at death. And they also teach that there are many other souls, that are we living beings or jivatmas. We jivatmas are not omnipresent soul but we are small atomic souls, and we travel and we leave the body at death.

Comment: You have confused between Jivâtman & Paramâtman. Advaita Vedânta states that the Jivâtman or the individual soul is of same essence as that of Paramâtman who is also referred to as Parabrahman but the Jivâtman can't realise this on being bound by Avidyâ. It is the Paramâtman that is all pervading, not the Jivâtman which remains confined in the snares of Avidyâ.